# Timeout when reading response headers from daemon process even after setting WSGIApplication group to Global

Tags: django, mod-wsgi

I am hosting a Django based webpage locally using Apache. However, I am getting the following error :

Timeout when reading response headers from daemon process 'office':var/www/office/office/wsgi.py.

I tried adding the line WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL} to the conf file, but still getting the same error.

This is my .conf file.

```
WSGIPythonPath /var/www/office

ServerName office.org
LoadModule wsgi_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_wsgi.so
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}

<VirtualHost 0.0.0.0:80>


ServerAlias www.office.org

DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/public_html

<Directory /var/www/example.com>
Require all granted
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/office/office>
<Files wsgi.py>
Require all granted
</Files>
</Directory>
WSGIDaemonProcess office python-home=/var/www/venv python-path=/var/www/office
WSGIProcessGroup office
WSGIScriptAlias /verify /var/www/office/office/wsgi.py process-group=office



ErrorLog /var/www/logs/error.log
CustomLog /var/www/logs/custom.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

This is wsgi.py file:

```
"""

WSGI config for office project.

It exposes the WSGI callable as a module-level variable named ``application``.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/deployment/wsgi/
"""

import os
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "office.settings")
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got the same problem and after a lot of struggling and trying different things, this [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-django-applications-with-apache-and-mod_wsgi-on-centos-7) helped me to solve the problems.

I created and successfully run the demo project. The problem for me were the paths in the config file and also using the server python version instead of creating a virtual environment for the project.

I hope it will help you

Comment: Thanks, it worked. The issue was I had forgotten to add the Alias and Directory Permission for the static Html pages. The link was helpful and saved a lot of time.

Answer (score 1):

I have got the same problem "Timeout when reading response headers" in Flask framework

I resolved it by adding **TimeOut 600** in httpd.conf/app.conf

Reference : https://ubiq.co/tech-blog/increase-request-timeout-apache/

Answer (score 0):

if this happened on a working server, You can try to force renew Your ssl certificate.
the reason could be found in apache error logs:
Name-based SSL virtual hosts only work for clients with TLS server name indication support (RFC 4366)

helped for me.